# Why changing input value manually can't emit input event?

Tags: javascript

Code is defined in [attachment](https://jsfiddle.net/qqogejdd/2/)

I have a situation, where I have an input field and input event attached to the field.

When I'm writing, removing etc. from this field, the event is emitted properly and I can react to this event.

```
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    changeCounterValue(charsCounter, input);
});
```

But when I submit a form with the input, I reset the value of the input, but it actually doesn't trigger my input event.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input.value = "";
  // I don't want to integrate here with charsCounter module, to reset his value to 0
});
```

My goal is to reset the value charsCounter without integreating in charsCounter module, because in this moment when I submit the form, charsCounter doesn't reset to 0.

Comment: changing values with JS won't trigger the event as it's not an event. Event is relative to interaction with DOM element and user interaction

Comment: instead you may define your own event and trigger it where you want

Comment: you don't want to reset the counter or what..?

Answer (score 1):

Natively, as @Temani Afif stated in the comments, the `input` event will not be triggered by changes from Javascript. Instead, you have to dispatch it yourself after resetting your value. Create the Element like this:

```
 var inputEvent = new Event('input', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
```

And trigger it in your `submit` EventListener like this:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input.value = "";
    // I don't want to integrate here with charsCounter module, to reset his value to 0
    input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x6tegmy/)

For further information, visit [MDN - Creating and triggering Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)